# Angular Ui-Grid Excel Export Fomatting

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

We are using the latest version of angular ui-grid and using exporter service to download excel files as:

```
 var rowTypes = uiGridExporterConstants.All
 var colTypes = uiGridExporterConstants.All
 uiGridExporterService.excelExport(grid, rowTpes, colTypes)
```

we are looking to format the exported excel and do things like add double borders on the headers, add some new rows as labels, merge some columns, etc.
I was trying the suggested example to add a new column in the data using one of the gridOptions 'exporterExcelCutomFormatters'

```
    gridOptions.exporterExcelCustomFormatters = function (grid, workbook, sheet, docDefinition) {
   const headerFormatter = docDefinition.styles['header'];
   let cols = [];
   // push data in A1 cell with metadata formatter
   cols.push({ value: 'Summary Report', metadata: {style: headerFormatter.id} });
   sheet.data.push(cols);
}
```

But few issues:
  - docDefinition is coming undefined? 
  - how can i merge first row to current columns size (5 columns )?
  - Is there a way to update css of exported header columns to have things like different color, double line headers, etc?

will appreciate any help?

Comment: I am not familiar with this function, however, there seems to be no `sheet` parameter in the interface of `gridOptions.exporterExcelCustomFormatters = function(grid, workbook, docDefinition)`.  (There is in `exporterExcelHeader` however...)

Also, there is an example in the ui-grid documentation: [410 Exporting Data with Fonts, Colors and Header in Excel](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20410%20Exporting%20Data%20with%20Fonts,%20Colors%20and%20Header%20in%20Excel).

Comment: Thanks.i think the documentation is not correct..they have given wrong input method in the example..i noticed the link you have mentioned and I think I am good now.